# Changes to file not visible in Sublime Text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, terminal, sublimetext3

So when I input for example:

```
$ echo "sample-text" > test.rb
```

and then input:

```
$ cat test.rb
```

It'll show `sample-text` within Terminal, but when I click on `test.rb` to open it with Sublime, it still shows the old content (i.e. overwriting is not effected within Sublime but within Terminal only)

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Foolish question, but since I've seen this tiny mistake being done many times before, it's worth asking. Are you sure you are in the same directory and changing the exact same file? (I know it may sound weird, but it's a common mistake)

Comment: Did you close the sublime tab and reopen the file?

Comment: If you have the `subl` command-line helper installed, try to open the file via `subl test.rb`. Otherwise, open the current directory in Finder by entering `open .` (note the dot). Then drag `test.rb` into Sublime Text.